# How to build a Json tree

Tags: c#

Here's the json I want to build:

```
{
    id: 0,
    item: [{ id: 1, text: "1111"
    }, {
        id: 2,
        text: "222222",
        item: [{ id: "21", text: "child" }]
        }, {
        id: 3, text: "3333"
    }]
}
```

For now I can not build a tree, I can only build something like this:

```
[{"id":1,"text":"1111"},{"id":21,"text":"child"]
```

I'm building it with this code:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var jsonString = serializer.Serialize(listOfPairsOfTextAndId);
```

But how can I build the given tree in c#?

Comment: Sorry, formatting threw me off. My mistake.

Comment: The keys of JSON objects have to be in quotes.

Comment: what is your data. I mean where is your original data.

Comment: @Shekhar The original data is a dictionary with a few pairs of id and text. I want to make the given tree.

Comment: @petko_stankoski you can see my edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Først issue is that it is somewhat difficult to use an anonymous object to describe your graph i C#. But you can create a class instead:

```
class Item {

  public Int32 id { get; set; }

  public String text { get; set; }

  public Item[] item { get; set; }

}
```

Then you can create your object graph:

```
var graph = new Item {
  id = 0,
  item = new[] {
    new Item {
      id = 1,
      text = "1111"
    },
    new Item {
      id = 2,
      text = "222222",
      item = new[] {
        new Item {
          id = 21,
          text = "child"
        }
      }
    },
    new Item {
      id = 3,
      text = "3333"
    }
  }
};
```

You are using the Microsoft JSON serializer which will result in this JSON:

```
{"id":0,"text":null,"item":[{"id":1,"text":"1111","item":null},{"id":2,"text":"222222","item":[{"id":21,"text":"child","item":null}]},{"id":3,"text":"3333","item":null}]}
```

This is not exactly what you want because of the extra `null` values. To work around this you can use [JSON.NET](https://json.codeplex.com/) instead. You have to add some extra attributes to the class being serialized:

```
class Item {

  public Int32 id { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
  public String text { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
  public Item[] item { get; set; }

}
```

Serialization is then performed using this code:

```
var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(graph);
```

You get this JSON:

```
{"id":0,"item":[{"id":1,"text":"1111"},{"id":2,"text":"222222","item":[{"id":21,"text":"child"}]},{"id":3,"text":"3333"}]}
```

Except for the syntax errors in your question this is what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create some objects that contain the data you want to serialize into that format. I used an online generator to create a couple of quick classes, refactor as necessary for your use.

Here are the classes

```
public class Item2
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public List<Item2> item { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public List<Item> item { get; set; }
}
```

You'll be creating the `RootObject` first and setting it's properties as necessary (make sure to init the List). After that, simply do the same for the other classes that will make up your output.

After you are done, simple Serialize the RootObject instance and you'll get the output requested.

I used http://json2csharp.com/ to generate those classes based on the desired JSON output.

Answer (score -1):

You can create function like this

```
   public static string GetJSON(object obj)
    {
        var oSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var sbJsonResults = new StringBuilder();
        oSerializer.Serialize(obj, sbJsonResults);
        return sbJsonResults.ToString();
    }
```

And then call this function.

### Edit 1

You can create a custom class in which form you want to use.

Create `List<class>` of that and pass it in the above function
It will work.